# OutOfMemoryError even with TestNG listeners/reporters disabled

Tags: java, maven, testng, heap-memory

I'm currently trying to run approximately 100,000 tests on a 32-bit Windows machine with 4GB RAM. I have disabled the default listeners with the command `-usedefaultlisteners false` and I don't have any custom listeners/reporters configured. However, the suite fails with the following stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-5" Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-7" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-6" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-4" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Is it possible that even without the listeners, TestNG configurations need more than 4GB RAM?

What process is requiring so much memory?

Are there any optimizations/workarounds to let these tests run?

Comment: Look into the surefire reports that were generated, inside `target/surefire-reports`, you'll have the full stacktrace.

Comment: Are you running the tests in `parallel`. If so, what kind of parallelism have you set in the `testng.xml`?

Comment: I am not using `parallel` settings in my testng.xml, but I have configured some tests to run with 15 threads by using the threadPoolSize attribute.

Comment: How have you configured Maven to run with? Are you forking the tests or reusing the JVM?

Comment: I am not using the surefire plugin, so I guess it is the default: forkCount=1/reuseForks=true

Comment: I had the same problem couple of years back.  Basically, testng stores results of each test no matter whether listener is enabled or not, it HAS to since it has to atleast give count of the tests that passed or failed.  I had millions of items to test, and testng usually conked at around 80,000 tests.  I finally had to come up with my own Executor based tests and my own reporting to get around this.  Imagine reports for a million data :)  In any case, you should profile and check in case your tests are leaking something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you hardware has 4GB Ram does not imply that its all used for JVM heap. The Heap size has a maximum value defined by parameter `-Xmx`.

In your case, with 4GB available, I would try to run the tests with this option :

```
java -Xmx2g mytest
```

This will allow up to 2GB for the heap.